# Select a date within a year in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Given:

```
INSERT INTO EP_ACCESS (PROFILE_ID, EPISODE_ID, START_TIMESTAMP, DISCONNECT_TIMESTAMP)
VALUES ('1', '1', TO_DATE('2020-01-01 00:00:01','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('2020-01-01 00:00:02','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

How can I select those who start_timestamp is in 2020?

Answer (score 3):

You would use:

```
where start_timestamp >= date '2020-01-01' and
      start_timestamp < date '2021-01-01'
```

Of course, you can use a `timestamp` literal if you prefer typing longer strings.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options.

1 - Use BETWEEN

```
SELECT *
  FROM EP_ACCESS
  WHERE START_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN TO_DATE('2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                            AND TO_DATE('2020-12-31 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM EP_ACCESS
  WHERE START_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN DATE '2020-01-01'
                            AND DATE '2021-01-01' - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
```

2 - Use EXTRACT

```
SELECT *
  FROM EP_ACCESS
  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM START_TIMESTAMP) = 2020
```

3 - Use TRUNC

```
SELECT *
  FROM EP_ACCESS
  WHERE TRUNC(START_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY') = DATE '2020-01-01'
```

Of these options, `BETWEEN` will probably provide the best performance as the other two require executing a function against the START_TIMESTAMP field in every row in the table.